# Is there a limit to the number of categories I can create?

Tags: categories

In Expression Engine 3.x is there a limit to the number of categories and sub-categories I can create? If so, how many?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there's no limit. However, the publish page might get a little unwieldy when using thousands of categories.